# Create function using external php library | shipping

Tags: php

I use [Inpost ShipX PHP SDK](https://github.com/imper86/php-inpost-api) php library one courier company to post/create shipping using API.

With this code I can get  shipping label and save, this working correct:

```
$shipmentData = json_decode($response->getBody()->__toString(), true);

while ($shipmentData['status'] !== 'confirmed') {
    sleep(1);
    $response = $api->shipments()->get($shipmentData['id']);
    $shipmentData = json_decode($response->getBody()->__toString(), true);
}

$labelResponse = $api->shipments()->label()->get($shipmentData['id'], [
    'format' => 'Pdf',
    'type' => 'A6',
]);

file_put_contents('var/labels/paczkomaty_label.pdf', $labelResponse->getBody()->__toString());
```

Now I try also get tracking number for created shipping.

I try add to above code:

```
$trackingResponse = $api->shipments()->tracking()->get($shipmentData['id']);

var_dump($trackingResponse);
```

But after post I get:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: InvalidArgumentException

Message: tracking resource not found

Filename: /vendor/imper86/php-inpost-api/src/Resource/AbstractResource.php

Line Number: 66
```

Can anyone check this library and help me build the function correctly or give me a hint how i can check the resource to build the right function?

Comment: Have you output the value of `$shipmentData` and made sure it contains what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Code for `__call` inside `/vendor/imper86/php-inpost-api/src/Resource/AbstractResource.php@66`:

```php
$className = $this->reflection->getName() . '\\' . ucfirst($name);
```

In your case it would be `Shipments\\Tracking`, but there is no such class.

Try doing

```
$api->tracking()->shippingHistory()->get($shipmentData['id']);
```

---

Basically what you see inside `src/Resouce` dir you can call as method.

---

I have just performed static analysis of code/structure, may be wrong

Comment: thank you for reply in my post. Now my code looks like: $trackingResponse = $api->tracking()->shippingHistory()->get($shipmentData['id']);

var_dump($trackingResponse);   but after this I get  An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: InvalidArgumentException

Message: shippingHistory resource not found

Filename: public_html/vendor/imper86/php-inpost-api/src/Resource/AbstractResource.php

Comment: I modified to $api->tracking()->serviceHistory according to files name in this library.  but we get below issue. I think this function is used for tracking history when we have ready tracking number. But currently in main function I post to create order and generate shipping label and in response I need var_dump generated shipping (tracking) label. and im not sure how to  var_dump in response tracking number which received generated shipping during order.

Comment: object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)#530 (6) { ["reasonPhrase":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> string(9) "Not Found" ["statusCode":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> int(404) ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> array(9) { ["Content-Type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "application/json;charset=UTF-8" } ["Date"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "Mon, 09 Jan 2023 16:10:24 GMT" } ["Server-Timing"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(41) "dtRpid;desc="847120365", dtSInfo;desc="0"" } ["Set-Cookie"]=> array(1) {